# How can i print the names of variables alive inside a function via decorator? - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

So, i've this code:

```
def checkScope(f):
    def inner(*args):
        res=f(*args)
        // I WANNA PRINT HERE BIM BUM AND BAM
        return res
    return inner

class A():
    @checkScope
    def first(self):
        bim = 5
        return self.second(bim)

    def second(self,m):
        if m < 8:
            bum = 6
        return self.third()

    def third(self):
        bam=2
        return bam

test=A()
test.first()
```

How can i print, inside the function checkScope, the variables bim bum and bam, using Inspect?

Comment: At the point where you say "I WANNA PRINT HERE BIM BUM AND BAM", *none of those variables actually exist* - as local variables, they vanished at the end of the containing function.

Comment: As @jasonharper mentioned, you cannot do that as the variables no longer exist at that point.
You could write a decorator such that if you used it on the `third` function, you can check the local variables of all outer scopes using a combination of `inspect.currentframe` and `inspect.outerframes`, but I am fairly confident there is no way to create a decorator that can give you the local variables of the function you use it on. You will have to determine that within the function call itself.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators can't put commands between your lines. Your variables only exist for the runtime of the function, so they cannot be read anywhere else. You'd have to define them as class variables or [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

The one thing you could do is to pass them all as parameters and read those.